# Invalid root in registry key when trying to get registry key value

Tags: php, registry

I'm trying to get registry key value using PHP but I'm getting an error saying

> Uncaught com_exception: ... Invalid root in the registry key

This is my code:

```
<?php

$Wshshell = new COM('WScript.Shell');

$data = $Wshshell->regRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip\Path');

echo "Data is::".$data;

?>
```

I copied this code from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418527/Registry-Key-Handling-Through-PHP)

I've seen other questions here but in C# and their accepted answer which is to add backslash to each backslash in the path did not solve my error.

[Here's the error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cee9F.png)

Comment: And do you have this key in your registry? Backslash is needed if using double quote in order to not treat it as escape sequence

Comment: Yes it's in the registry.

Comment: you have to run this php script as admin for some registry.